# How to ignore string types in function?

Tags: string, function, average

I have a function average(), which summarize numbers and make average of it. This function has to ignore any string types.

```
function average() {
    let total = Number('');
    let num = arguments.length;

  for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    
   total += arguments[i];
    
  }
  return total / num;`
```

average(10, "20", 30, "40", 50, "60", 70, "80", 90, "100"));

I expected here: 50

I've tride to use parseInt, isNan, but it doesn't work. Probably I made something wrong

Comment: What if you do `Number(arguments[i]);` what happens then?

Comment: Same issue. I've tried it too